# I need help on an issue with the roof of my porch I'm designing

Tags: roof, code-compliance, deck, design, porch

The porch is has to have a chamfer due to space limitations from a dry creek very close to it. I'd like to do an A-frame but may need to do a shed roof if  needed. The roof would have to hang off into space without a support as seen in my photos. Is this allowed under building codes or even just structurally sound? Maybe a diagonal support beam of some kind could extend from the porch?
https://imgur.com/a/SgCx8oE

Comment: No interest in a hip style roof?

Answer (score 1):

What you propose in the drawings CAN be allowed if it is designed and or signed off by an engineer.

Try finding a draftsman in your area that can draw the plans and have them certified by an engineer. A local draftsman should know the codes for your location and can allow for them. That is a less expensive alternative than having an engineer or engineering company draw the plans.

Only then will you know the "how" and "with what" about building the roof you want.